# PHP File Saves XML in Browser but not as a scheduled .bat file

Tags: php, xml, batch-file

I've got a PHP file that when run in the browser saves a number of XML files successfully as follows:

```
$fileName = 'savedFiles/'.$invoiceNumber.'xml';

// Save XML
$xml->asXML();

//Format XML to save indented tree rather than one line
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());

$dom->save($fileName);
```

I'd like to schedule this PHP file to be performed via the Windows Task Scheduler, so have setup a simple .bat file as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
php.exe -f "C:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\HTTPServer\conf\sites\processDownloads.php"
```

When this is executed via the Task Scheduled no .xml files are generated - I'm getting this error in the Application Log:

```
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::save(xml_files/Invoice123.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files\FileMaker\FileMaker Server\HTTPServer\conf\sites\processDownloads.php on line 442
```

Line 442 is the line that saves the XML:

```
$dom->save($fileName);
```

I've set the task schedule to run as Admin and "Run with highest privileges" is selected. I can't see any permissions issues, especially given it works in the browser and the schedule is set to run as Administrator.

Comment: You probably need to change the working directory from the batch script because your save path is relative. Or use an absolute path if possible.

Comment: Thanks - I had to set the Start In directory to the same directory where the php file was stored and it all worked after that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Setting the "Start in (optional)" value to the same location as the .php file I was calling fixed this for me.